# Attribute extraction using buffer on top of a raster layer

Tags: raster, point, buffer, attribute-joins, overlay

How can I extract attribute information from a raster map?

I work with camera traps and I am interested in collecting habitat information off a raster sheet. I am interested in a certain radius around the point. In the past, I used a buffer around the camera points and extracted the information, but that was not using a raster layer.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the community tour here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour  and edit your question to include anything that you have tried and what, specifically, you are stuck at.

Comment: Please include your software and version as a tag.

Comment: In general, if you have a point layer for your cameras, create a buffer as before and then there are a number of options dependent on the software you are using that will allow you to sample pixel values within the buffers. But as tom said, need to know your software.